# DIv visibility:hidden not working, Control the visibility, without modifying the display, of elements - Bootstrap DIv tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap

I have the code as below...

```css
.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8" *ngIf="loggedInUser && !loggedInUser.isPresident" style="visibility: hidden;">
          <button pButton icon="pi" type="button" label="Create ABC Case" (click)="createABC()"></button>&nbsp;
          <button pButton icon="pi" type="button" label="Create XYZ Case"  (click)="createXYZ()"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="loggedInUser && (loggedInUser.isPresident || loggedInUser.isVP)">
          <button pButton icon="pi" type="button" label="Print" (click)="test()"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to retain the DIV space when the 1st div condition passes. Say I logged in as President then I should not see the buttons but the page should retain the DIV and move the next DIV to the right.

I tried using `style="visibility: hidden;"` but it didn't help. Used `class=visible` like `class="col-sm-8 visible"` and corresponding css as but still didn't get the DIV to occupy the space. The Print button moves to left side. How can this be avoided?

Comment: doesn't the `ngIf` remove the DIV node from the DOM if it doesn't pass?

Comment: Check out this [article](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngif-else/) and goto the section "NgIf vs hidden" and read the difference. Sounds like you want to use `[hidden]` instead of `ngIf`